# Hiding titlebar without hiding taskbar icon

Tags: python, user-interface, pysimplegui

I'm building an desktop GUI app using PySimpleGUI. I want to hide the titlebar of the app's window but without hiding the taskbar icon like i.e Spotify. I've tried using no_titlebar flag in my window but it hides the taskbar icon.

Comment: if your using `pysimplegui` why do you have tags for `tkinter`

Comment: tkinter doesn't supply a taskbar icon when creating a window without a titlebar. It's a tkinter thing. There is a demo of custom titlebars that was added to the PySimpleGUI demos. It will show a taskbar icon when the custom titlebar window is minimized.  I think it could be modified to create a taskbar entry all the time if desired.